# Connect my php code to mysql for user data

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know how to make the code below connect to mysql, because everything is connected so I am confused about how to switch the database user from php to mysql.
taken from "user" database connection fetched from "config.php"

```
<?php
// List containing the registered chat users:
$users = array();

// Default guest user (don't delete this one):
$users[0] = array();
$users[0]['userRole'] = 1;
$users[0]['userName'] = null;
$users[0]['password'] = null;
$users[0]['channels'] = array(0);
```

Comment: I think you probably haven't any information about databases and exactly what mysql is.
i recommend first read about mysql. maybe this site be useful. https://www.mysqltutorial.org/what-is-mysql/

Comment: @AliChoopani 
I understand quite well, I didn't understand how to use it in php / html

Comment: you said "switch the database user from php to mysql". it means you don't even know difference between programming language like php and a database like mysql.